# jQuery events within dynamic content via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, dynamic

Is there a way I can load content dynamically using ajax and retain any jquery functionality that the loaded content may have?

For example, I'd like to load in a Twitter like feed of DB records.  Each record can be voted thumbs up or thumbs down.  The voting uses some AJAX and I can't retain event functionality when loaded into a parent page.

ok forgive such a noob question but I'm lost with the example on the jquery page. 
When it says:

```
$('a').click(fn); 
$('#mydiv').load('my.html',function(){ 
$('a').click(fn); });
```

what is fn supposed to represent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **event delegation**, [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) will do the trick.  It has a lot more advantages than just retaining functionality too.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). http://api.jquery.com/live/